# Flip animation (ObjectAnimator) for supportfragment (API less than 10)

Tags: android, animation, actionbarsherlock, fragment, objectanimator

I tried use CustomAnimation function for my application. But I end up getting Unknown Object Animator name error. I did some research and found out apparently objectAnimator type of animation is not supported under getSupportFragmentManager (correct me if i'm wrong).

```
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out,
                R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out)
                .add(R.id.content_frame, reportPage,reportPage.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(reportPage.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .commit();

        getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

I saw multiple threads mentioned use http://nineoldandroids.com/ for ObjectAnimator. But I don't have an idea of how to use this library to implement it on my application.

Is there any workaround that I can use Object Animator type of animation in the above function?

Comment: please did you google, because ive seen more than 4 post about your questions and answer that has 3 figure vote ups.. so you might wona check if they solve your problem

Comment: @Elltz If possible could you provide me the post that you mentioned? Hopefully I did not miss out any other posts that is helpful. I saw like 2-3 post with 3 figures use Native SDK with API 14 and above. Which my case is compatibility library (sherlock), sadly I can't apply that.

Comment: i could write you an animation xml, would you welcome that